# accessing child of click handler

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div id="TheTable">
    <div class="TheRow">
        <div class="Col Col1">col1</div>
        <div class="Col Col2">col2</div>
        <div class="Col Col3">col3</div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm binding a click handler for rows, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#TheTable').on({
        click: function () { alert('clicked on row'); }
    }, '.TheRow');

});
```

As you can see, a click on any cell of a row triggers the click function.

I want to change this so that when a click happens, I can get the index or the class of the `Col` element that was actually clicked on. So for instance, if the lick happened on a `.Col2` element, I want to get the index (ie. 1) or the class (ie. `Col Col2`).

How do I do this?

**The jsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3hPEU/).**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **2 options:**

```
$('#TheTable').on({
    click: function (e) {
        var target_index = $(e.target).index();
        alert('clicked on row ' + target_index);
    }
}, '.TheRow');
```

This will give you the index of 0,1 or 2 of your example.

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/YbV3b/)**

---

And you can use this to get the class (respecting the second class is always in the position "second"):

```
$('#TheTable').on({
    click: function (e) {
        var classes = $(e.target).prop('class').split(' ')[1];
        alert('clicked on row ' + classes);
    }
}, '.TheRow');
```

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/UxFvy/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#TheTable').on({
    click: function (e) { alert($(e.target).index()); }
}, '.TheRow');
```

[**Updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3hPEU/2/)

Answer (score 1):

use `e.target` to get the targeted element .. `attr('class')` or `prop()` to get the corresponding class

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#TheTable').on({
    click: function (e) {

        alert($(e.target).attr('class'));
    }
}, '.TheRow');

});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3hPEU/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use jQuery's `index()` function. It gets the element number inside of a container

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#TheTable').on("click", function () {
        var number = $(".TheRow").index() + 1; // get element number and add 1
        alert('clicked on row ' + number);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hPEU/3/)

Answer (score 0):

i would go for such a code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.Col').on('click',function () 
        { alert('clicked on row');
         alert($(this).attr('class'));
        });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this to get class and index :

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$('#TheTable .TheRow div').on('click',function () {
    var i = $('#TheTable .TheRow div').index(this);
    var c = $(this).attr('class');
    alert("index: "+i+",Class: "+c);
});
```

});